# ValidationGroup and validating multiple textbox efficiently asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a sign up page that has a text box for several required fields (email, user name, password, etc...).

Is there a way to validate all of these are not empty and only have one error message show up if any of these aren't filled out? I know that I'll probably have to have a RequiredFieldValidator for all these forms, but if they all have a error message, won't the error message show up for every failed validation instead of just a generic "Please fill out all required fields" message.

I thought that validationgroup could fix this, but these text boxes will have other validations besides just the RequiredFieldValidator and I figure that would be problematic because I don't think you can assign one text box to more than 1 validationGroup? Is there a best practice way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried validation summery  http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2008/10/validationsummary-example-how-to-use.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ASP.NET [Custom Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control. You can tweak it to have custom validation logic for **any** number of controls, which I believe  is what you're looking for. It also has functionality to validate input on both the client (by using javascript) and/or the server.

I'll show you an example using server-side validation, if you need this to work on the client as well have a look at [ClientValidationFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**ASPX:**

```
First Name:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
Last Name:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
Email Address:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="SignUp" />&nbsp;
<asp:CustomValidator ID="signUpValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please fill in all the fields first"
    ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="ValidateSignUp"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void ValidateSignUp(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    bool hasFirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Length > 0 ? true : false;
    bool hasLastName = txtLastName.Text.Length > 0 ? true : false;
    bool hasEmail = txtEmailAddress.Text.Length > 0 ? true : false;

    if (hasFirstName && hasLastName && hasEmail)
        args.IsValid = true;
    else
        args.IsValid = false;
}

protected void SignUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        //All the required fields have been filled in, sign the user up
    }   
}
```